# Class 'Yaf_Application' not found

Tags: php, frameworks

Is anyone know the Yaf Framework ?

I tried to run their sample code from the site and I got the error
Fatal error: Class 'Yaf_Application' not found.

I used the version 2.2.9  ,  I downloaded the binaries php_yaf-2.2.9-x86-5.4.x-nts-nodebug.dll
as extension of my PHP 5.4.3  and activated the extension.

I put , as suggested, yaf.use_namespace = 0   without success.

Thank you for your help

Comment: php -i in the console. Did you stop and restart whatever server you are using too?

Comment: Actually, I'm using Wamp. I restart it and when I look to PHP extensions in the wamp menu, I can see that yaf.dll is checked  @mpm  but when I check phpinfo, I cannot see yaf !

Answer (score 1):

I have also faced same problem, after some google, I am able to fix this issue.
If you ae using wamp and Win32 means, in php.ini add the following line after extension=php_yaf.dll

yaf.use_spl_autoload=1 
yaf.use_namespace=1

Comment: Works fine YAF 2.3.5 On x86 PHP 5.6.*

Answer (score 0):

I found that my dll does not run on 64bit operating system